# improper DOM issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, dom

I have a page which loads and then I do some JQuery upon it. When doing the line:

```
var div = $("<div class='modal'>").append(r);
```

I was trying to figure out why it was erroring out and saying there was a Hierarchy error.  Maybe there is improper DOM in r? To save on the output as it is long, I will show the server side. r below does not error, but it is when appending it with the div above where the issues actually occur.

```
var r = $(result);
```

result:

```
"<div>
   <input type='text' id ='queryInput' />
   <button id = 'queryButton' runat='server' value = 'Re-Filter'>Re-Filter</button>
</div>
<div id='set'>
   <select>
     <!-- The options are populated by a loop in ASP.net -->
     <option value = '" + Convert.ToString(record.fe_id) + "'>" + Convert.ToString(record.fe_name) + "</option>  
   </select>
</div>
<div>
   <button id = 'buttonReturnValue' value = 'Return Selected Element'>Return Selected Element</button>
</div>"
```

What am I doing wrong where it thinks the above is improperly formed dom?

Comment: for the person(s) who posted answers and removed it before i could downvote.  1) the definition of "<div>" in a jquery statement is sound and still has the error i am trying to resolve.2) I was assigning it to a JS var, the next line was doing: $("div.modal").replaceWith(div);.

Comment: -1 for asking a question and take care of downvoting of answers after a couple of minutes.

Comment: i didnt downvote after 3 minutes.  The people removed them as they indeed retracted their answers before i could discuss with them.  The answers they has supplied were wrong.  Hence it was "unhelpful"...  Or should i be waiting until the answer is discovered before giving out my point rewards?

Comment: You should care about your question, not about deleted answers

Comment: correct thats what i was doing bud.  They gave an answer which they deleted.  If others want to look at this, then the cant see their solution which was incorrect.  I wanted to document the attempt and where it had veered incorrectly.

Comment: Currently I don't think the deleted answers(I can see them ;)) are more incorrect than your question. I was trying the code above and it works well, so something must be missing inside your question. However, the error-message doesn't say the DOM is wrong, it says the DOM can't be inserted where you want to.

Comment: Question resolved. +1 for you for helping.  Going to edit original Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var text = "<div><input type='text' id ='queryInput' /><button id = 'queryButton' runat='server' value = 'Re-Filter'>Re-Filter</button></div><div id='set'><select><option value = '" + Convert.ToString(record.fe_id) + "'>" + Convert.ToString(record.fe_name) + "</option></select></div><div><button id = 'buttonReturnValue' value = 'Return Selected Element'>Return Selected Element</button></div>";
```

This is a workaround but works...

```
var d = document.createElement("div");
d.innerHTML = text;
document.getElementById('modal').appendChild(d);
```

Comment: 1)  I think you want it to be reversed:  d.appendChild(document.getElementById("addhere")); which still gets the hierarchical error i am trying to resolve.

Comment: Opps, I misunderstood your question but I think your question is not doable. How can you add DOM to something which is not present in the page at the time or processing and expect to see it is working?

Comment: I did an Ajax request which returned a string, which is then parsed into actual content and rendered on the screen in much the similar way you are doing here....  just creating a new node and then giving it an innerHTML = the string more or less.

Comment: This does the same thing as the answer;  This answer would've been correct had the text variable in which is give was text.  It was actually a js object containing text.  Under revised conditions, your code would work.